# How to add a custom "under maintenance" page?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, maintenance-mode

I'm trying to add a custom page to my web application for the times I'm performing maintenance.

I'm trying to test the referred page on my development environment but the Symfony page always appears. I had already created a module with a proper action and template and also configured those on the `settings.yml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this: ["Website Temporarily Unavailable" error page](http://www.symfony-check.org/permalink/customize-the-website-temporarily-unavailable-page)

Comment: Hi there!

I've tried your suggestion and it worked! I've created a page called unavailable.php and placed it under the project_name/config/ directory. However, I'm having some troubles with the page enconding; characters like 'ã' are not appearing in thr proper way. 

Can anyone give me some help?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

In your app's settings.yml set these:

```
all:
  .settings:
    module_disabled_module: security   # To be called when a user requests 
    module_disabled_action: disabled  # A module disabled in the module.yml
```

In the module's module.yml set this:

```
prod: 
  enabled:     false
```

This will disable the your module for prod environment, but it will still be available for dev and test environments.

Hope it helps.
Regards,
Radu.